# How to access the method of other class in other namespace?

Tags: c#

//Given below is the main program in a particular namespace and class.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
   class Class1
    {
        static void Main()
        {
                Program pg = new Program();//this is the other class in other name space
                    pg.displayy(); //i  want to use this function 
               Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

//    ---------------------------------------
//    and other program name is : program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplicationexample2
{
    class Program
    {
        void displayy()
        {
            int a = 6;
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: add reference to the other namespace in your project and then access it after including its namespace by using statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In case of a static method:**

```
namespaceName.ClassName.MethodName ();
```

**In case of a non-static method:**

create an instance of the class by :

```
namespaceName.ClassName instance = new  namespaceName.ClassName();
```

and then invoke the wanted method by:

```
instance.MethodName();
```

Comment: @Vibhore jain, need any other help?

Answer (score 1):

Add an `using` to the top of the ConsoleApplication3.cs file:

```
using ConsoleApplicationexample2;
```

And if the referenced class is in another project, also add a reference to that project to your other project. Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer, and click `Add Reference`.

Comment: ,To add to that, the other assembly has to be referenced

Answer (score 1):

To be able to access method of other class both method and class must be `public`:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public void displayy()
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```